# hyperplane separating point in convex hull from compact set

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

If a point is inside the convex hull of a compact set, then could it be proved that every hyperplane with the compact set on 1 side will always have that point $x$ on the same side?

Comment: What do you understand by " convex hull" ?

Comment: I understand the idea and visual, but I'm not sure how to prove it

Comment: If the compact set lies on one side of the hyperplane then so does its convex hull, hence the answer is yes (assuming I understood correctly).

Comment: That doesn't seem so obvious to me.  all i get from the definition is that it's the intersection of all convex sets containing some set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is a set such that $\phi(a) \le \alpha $ for all $a \in A$ where $\phi$ is a linear functional and $\alpha$ is some constant.

Note that the set $H = \{x | \phi(x) \le \alpha \}$ is convex and
$A \subset H$. Since $\operatorname{co} A$ is the intersection of
all convex sets containing $A$ we see that $\operatorname{co} A \subset H$ and hence any point in $\operatorname{co} A$ lies in the 'same side' of the hyperplane $\{x | \phi(x) = \alpha \}$ as $A$.